# iOS NSCoding Implementation

Tags: ios, nscoding

I have a custom object which I want to persist to disk rather than memory.  The custom object has sub objects which have sub objects and so on.  The tree is quite extensive.  There are over 30 properties in one of the sub objects 6 of which are sub objects themselves.

If I want to use NSCoding, do I need to implement NSCoding on each sub custom object and implement encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder in each custom object?

I am thinking the answer is YES, but this is going to be a pain in the butt to do, just busy work going through each object and making it NSCoding compliant basically right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Thankfully Accessorizer exists exactly for this reason: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/accessorizer/id402866670?mt=12

Comment: woo hoo! And here I thought I would have to write dozens of keys to archives. This thing looks very promising